# Clang vs GCC vs MSVC - using brace-enclosed initializer list to create user defined type?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, c++11, clang

Was experimenting with brace-enclosed initializer list and compilers seems to behave differently (well, it's a fairly new feature), but was wondering what should be the correct behavior and especially if 'c3' mentioned below should actually compiles with private, default initialized variable?

```
int main() {
    struct c1 {
        bool b;
        char c;
        int i;
    };

    auto c1_ = c1{true, '0', 0};
    //clang-3.6 - okay
    //gcc-4.9   - okay
    //vs-2013   - okay

    // ------------------------------------------

    struct c2 {
        bool b;
        char c;
        int i = 0; // with default value
    };

    auto c2_ = c2{true, '0', 0};
    //clang-3.6 - okay
    //gcc-4.9   - error: no matching function for call to ‘c2::c2(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
    //vs-2013   - error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'c2'

    auto c2__ = c2{true, '0'};
    //clang-3.6 - okay
    //gcc-4.9   - error: no matching function for call to ‘c2::c2(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
    //vs-2013   - error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'c2'

    // ------------------------------------------

    struct c3 {
        bool b;
        char c;
    private:
        int i = 0; // with private default value
    };

    auto c3_ = c3{true, '0'};
    //clang-3.6 - error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'c3'
    //gcc-4.9   - error: no matching function for call to ‘c3::c3(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
    //vs-2013   - error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'c3'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is aggregate initialization.

C++11 paragraph that defines an aggregate says (n3337, §8.5.1/1):

> An *aggregate* is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided
>   constructors (12.1), *no brace-or-equal* initializers for non-static data
>   members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause
>   11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

This means that `c2` is not an aggregate and `auto c2_ = c2{true, '0', 0};` should trigger a diagnostic in C++11 (and gcc is right).

However, with clang, you seem to compile in C++14 mode, which removed the "no brace-or-equal initializers" limitation (n3690, §8.5.1/1):

> An *aggregate* is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided
>   constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members
>   (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions
>   (10.3).

So, `auto c2_ = c2{true, '0', 0};` is okay in C++14.

About `auto c2__ = c2{true, '0'};`, §8.5.1/7 (n3690) says:

> If there are fewer *initializer-clauses* in the list than there are
>   members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized
>   shall be initialized from its *brace-or-equal-initializer* or, if there
>   is no *brace-or-equal-initializer*, from an empty initializer list
>   (8.5.4).

Which means it's ok and clang is right to compile it in C++14 mode.

`c3` is not an aggregate (because of private member) neither in C++11 nor in C++14 so all compilers are correct to reject it.

Comment: "However, clang seems to apply C++14 here" He's compiling in C++14 mode. If clang is set to C++11 mode it produces errors for the `c2` initializers.

Comment: yep, example was compiled in c++14 mode, seems gcc didnt implement c++14 rules yet, anyway what was the motivation to limit an aggregate only to private members? seems like private initialized members would be fine, wouldn't they?

Comment: @Kris I can't say with any authority, but the concept of aggregate goes all the way back to C, where access specifiers are non-existent. Furthermore, C++ makes no guarantee about the relative layout between members with different access level, so allowing aggregate initialization of such types would make it pretty non-portable.

Answer (score 2):

```
 auto c2_ = c2{true, '0', 0};
 auto c2__ = c2{true, '0'};
```

These are fine in C++14. The in-class initialization does not stop the type from being an aggregate in C++14, and the in-class value will be used when a value is not provided by the brace-initializer.

```
auto c3_ = c3{true, '0'};
```

This is an error, because aggregates cannot have `private:` or `protected:` members. Since it's not an aggregate you only have the implicitly declared default constructor. You can do the following:

```
auto c3_ = c3{};
```

Answer (score 2):

`c2` is not an aggregate in C++11, but is in C++14. So the code should not compile in the former, and should in the latter. It looks like clang is compiling in C++14 mode.

`c3` is not an aggregate due to the presence of a `private` data member, so it should not compile, regardless of the standard..